# NSNumberFormatter: dispatch_once where Currency changes

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I have a tableview where a list of `NSDecimalNumber` will be displayed with their own currencies.

I use a `dispatch_once` on a `NSNumberFormatter` but notice that sometimes it'll totally ignore my commands to set the fraction digits or suffix on fraction digits altogether.

Currently the only way I've been able to resolve this is to init the `NSNumberFormatter` every row which is a bit silly.

ie:

```
- (NSNumberFormatter *)currencyFormatWithCurrency:(NSString *)currency
{
    static NSNumberFormatter *_formatter = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        _formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    });

    [_formatter setCurrencyCode:currency];
    [_formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [_formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
    [_formatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:NO];
    [_formatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];

    return _formatter;
}

// someCurrency is a string that will change per row
// someAmount is a NSDecimalNumber that will change per row
  NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [self currencyFormatWithCurrency:someCurrency];
    NSString *formattedAmount = [formatter stringFromNumber:someAmount];

    self.amountLabel.text = formattedAmount;
```

Sometimes with the above if I feed in a figure like `80000`, it'll return `80,000.00` (sometimes it depends on the currency).

I guess I could just init the `NSNumberFormatter` and nil it on each row.

Perhaps I'm doing it wrong, but if there is perhaps a way to ensure that I don't need to keep creating the `NSNumberFormatter` to ensure it'll understand the rules I give it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSNumberFormatter is not thread safe. That will lead to all kinds of problems. (Well, the way you use it cannot really be thread safe, because you might be modifying it in one thread while another thread is using it, but just using an NSNumberFormatter from two threads is not safe).

You can always do something in a method like

```
NSString* lastCurrency = nil;
NSNumberFormatter* formatter = nil; 

for (;;) {
    ...
    NSString* currency = ...;
    if (! [lastCurrency isEqualToString:currency]) {
        lastCurrency = currency; 
        formatter = ...;
    }
}
```

Works well if in most cases the currency is unchanged.

Comment: Okay, isn't that what the dispatch_once is meant to do. Perhaps a better solution  there something else you would suggest?

Comment: dispatch_once creates a formatter _once_ per program. This code creates a new formatter each time you ask for a different currency. And you get a new formatter for each thread. Notice the "static" in your code? static variables are there for _every_ code and for _every_ thread. If you run the code above on ten threads, you get ten formatters, and you _need_ ten formatters because they are not thread safe.

Comment: Looks like there is a good possible solution here; http://engineering.hoteltonight.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-ios-internationalization-and-localization

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a possible solution which I got from the following [website](http://engineering.hoteltonight.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-ios-internationalization-and-localization) might help things.

```
NSString *HTCurrencyString(double amount, NSString *currencyCode)
{
    static NSString *currencyFormatterKey = @"HTCurrencyFormatter";
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary][currencyFormatterKey];
    if (currencyFormatter == nil)
    {
        currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [currencyFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

        [[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary][currencyFormatterKey] = currencyFormatter;
    }
    [currencyFormatter setCurrencyCode:currencyCode];
    [currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
    [currencyFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
    return [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:@(amount)];
}
```

Comment: The only problem I have now is that it sometimes doesn't respect the rules I put here.  Sometimes it'll put suffix ".00" at the end of it, other times it won't.     The only solution I have for now is to force strip suffix ".00" from the formatted string `NSString *formattedAmount = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:(amount)]; formattedAmount = [formattedAmount stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".00" withString:[NSString string]]; return formattedAmount;`